# Can I extort Launch Party with the creature I'm sacrificing?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

If I control exactly 1 [Basilica Screecher](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Basilica%20Screecher), and I cast [Launch Party](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Launch%20Party) sacrificing my Basilica Screecher, can I still use Basilica Screecher to extort on Launch Party?

Comment: ... Do you mean Launch Party instead of Slaughter Games?

Comment: @AlexP yes I did.  Those 4-mana rakdos spells are all the same to me

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No. Basilica Screecher will no longer be on the battlefield when the spell becomes cast, so its ability will not trigger.

---

Casting a spell:

1. Placing it on the stack. [CR 601.2a]
2. Make choices (e.g. modes, targets) that need to be made to cast the spell. [CR 601.2b-d]
3. Determine the total cost to cast the spell. [CR 601.2e]
4. Activate mana abilities. [CR 601.2f]
5. Pay the total cost. [CR 601.2g]

Only once all of the above has happened is the spell cast, so only then would abilities that trigger on casting the spell trigger.

> 601.2h Once the steps described in 601.2a–g are completed, the spell becomes cast. Any abilities that trigger when a spell is cast or put onto the stack trigger at this time. If the spell’s controller had priority before casting it, he or she gets priority.

However, you sacrificed [Basilica Screecher](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Basilica%20Screecher) back in step 5 (601.2g), so it's no longer on the battlefield when you completed the casting of the spell, meaning its ability will not trigger.

Comment: Yours is better. I'll just edit yours. ;)

Comment: @Alex P, I always mean a concise answer at the top, but I forgot this time. Thanks for adding it.